# C# evaluate for a value greater than 0 given 3 variables

Tags: c#

Is it more efficient to use: if ( a+b+c > 0) or if ( a>0 || b>0|| c>0) or is there a better way than either of these?

Comment: 1) Comparisons like that are cheap, so unless you're running them literally tens of millions of times you don't need to worry about efficiency. 2) If any of the values can be negative then those two expressions are not identical; for example, if a = 1, b = 0, and c = -1 then the first expression will be false while the second will be true.

Comment: You can easily benchmark both and know which one is faster in your specific environment.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Agreed.  The two expressions are not equivalent to begin with so this question is invalid.

Comment: Depending on the result of whichever expression you choose, do you use a, b and/or c again?

Comment: Readability, Maintainability etc are way more important than a CPU cycle more

Comment: @MatthewFrontino That is correct, unless the data type is unsigned.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You could take the more extreme case where a + b + c results in an overflow as well, so maybe that case is invalid too.  Regardless, I agree the comparisons are cheap both ways and readability/maintainability above all

Comment: Oblivious Sage answered perfectly, even accounting for my imperfect question.  New to this site, not sure if I am supposed to accept an answer or do something else, but I'm satisfied with the first answer.

Answer (score 3):

These two expressions are not equivalent: the first expression will be `false` for `a=1, b=0, c=-1`, while the second will be `true`.

The first expression would require two additions, a comparison to zero, and a branch, while the second expression would require up to three comparisons to zero and up to three branches, because `||` operator is short-circuiting. In the end, the difference is going to be undetectably small.

The only case when the second expression would win is when `a`, `b` and `c` represent expensive computations:

```
if (ExpensiveComputationA() > 0
||  ExpensiveComputationB() > 0
||  ExpensiveComputationC() > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Since the computation above would stop after the first success, the resultant code could be significantly faster as a result of short-circuiting expensive branches.